# jQuery bxSlider not working in responsive

Tags: jquery, css, bxslider

jQuery bxSlider not working while on responsive. It works well on a big screen.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('.slider1').bxSlider({
 pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
 auto: true,
 autoControls: true,
 slideWidth: 1500,
 minSlides: 1,
 maxSlides: 1,
 slideMargin: 10
 });
 });
```

What property have I missed for responsive? Anybody help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or live link to problem this way it will easier for us to debug the problem

Comment: well this link isnt working for me, i got this error "The 192.168.1.4 page isn’t working, 192.168.1.4 didn’t send any data.", I suggest u to create jsfiddle so we can have a look

Comment: check in this link 192.168.1.4/helixtech-newhome

Comment: Hmm ok i'll send u the fiddle link

Comment: Jsfiddle not working.. Kindly check in this link http://httest.in/home/

Answer (score 0):

you can use that jquery lib "fitvid.js" and make it work on the slider to make it responsive 
the link for the lib : http://fitvidsjs.com/
or you can use a grid system based framework like bootstrap and foundation
or just make it by media queries like that :
    @media screen and (put here the max or min width) {
        put here the fixed width and height you want for the bx-slider
    }

Answer (score 0):

can you please remove slideWidth: 1500, and check

Comment: Removed slideWidth. But rersponsive problem occurs

Comment: Have you assigned height some where ?? Parents elements or images height ??

Answer (score 0):

bxslider has "responsive" option so u can set it true like "responsive: true"

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider1').bxSlider({
        pagerCustom: '#bx-pager',
        auto: true,
        autoControls: true,
        slideWidth: 1500,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 1,
        responsive: true,
        slideMargin: 10
    });
});
```

see the docs [here](http://bxslider.com/options#responsive)

Comment: Text goes down.. While reducing under 721px. And Width dynamically set to 450px.